# How do capybara ancestor and sibling instance methods actually work?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Typically when I had to find siblings, I had to do this:

`find('#child').find(:xpath, '..').find(#some-other-child-from-this-parent)`

Does using `sibling` replace this entire line?

Does `ancestor` replace the call to traverse upwards in the `xpath` selector?

How "far down" do these instance methods navigate?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybaras `ancestor` and `sibling` methods are called on an element and take the same parameters as `find`. They are implemented by locating all elements that match the passed in parameters and intersecting that with the set of ancestor or sibling elements respectively. From your example finding a sibling of the element with id of 'child' could be like

```
find('#child').sibling('.some_class')
```

which would return an element with the class `some_class` which is a sibling of the element with id of `child`. `ancestor` works the same way but looks up the document tree at all the elements ancestors.

```
td_element.ancestor('table')
```

would return the `table` element which is the ancestor of the previously found `td` element